# Copying layer from photoshop (linked mask layers?)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I downloaded a PSD from http://iconsweets.com/

The PSD has several icons, each on its own layer. I think they use linked layer masks or something, but I can't figure out how to copy just one icon to use it in a new file.

How do I copy one icon/layer including the styles so that I can easily change the color of it?

Comment: I'm looking for the same solution, any news? Faisal
I have tried your method and the icon is save but with the full page size not the icon size.
Also on a big file like that it's take forever, even if you select visible item only it's check all layers. I know there is a better way (I don't remember how)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way: Target the layer you want to copy. With the Move (black arrow) tool active, drag *from the canvas* (NOT the Layers panel) to the new document. If your documents are tabbed, drag onto the tab for the target document then release the mouse when you're on its canvas. That will pull the entire layer, styles and all.

Comment: And make sure Global Light is the same in the destination document, or the layer styles might look a little strange.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following: Go the menu of Photoshop CS
File | Scripts | Export Layers to Files
Here you will see and option box where you want to save the desired icons in the folder (Destination) create the Prefix of your logical file name enable or disable the check box of (Visible Layers Only) then Select the File type in the list and Press the Run Button. You wait and make a sip of coffee and icons or images are in separate folder that you assign first.